# how to use export for .bashrc

Tags: bash, gcc, centos, libstdc++

I modified the .bashrc and .bash_profile of a server. I installed locally 2 things:

1. a software for data analysis called ROOT
2. an update version of gcc. This is due to the current version of my server did not satisfy the minimum requirements of certain software.

I modified both `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` to be able to access ROOT by just typing `root`  on my terminal and to use the updated version `gcc`.

My `.bashrc`  looks like:

```
export PATH=/emph/app/ydeniz/local/bin:${PATH}
export ROOTSYS=/emph/app/ydeniz/Cern-Root2/root
export PATH=$PATH:$ROOTSYS/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ROOTSYS/lib
export PATH=/emph/app/ydeniz/local/GCC-8.2.0/bin:${PATH}
```

Both commands `root` and `gcc` work as expected. However when adding more lines for a different software like this:

```
# Where path/to/ is the PATH of libstdc++.so.6 on my gcc 
# (locally installed) updated version
LD_LIBRARY_PATH= path/to/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I get this error after `source .bashrc` :

```
bash: /emph/app/ydeniz/local/GCC-8.2.0/lib64/::/emph/app/ydeniz/Cern-Root2/root/lib:/emph/app/ydeniz/Cern-Root2/root/lib: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You need to remove the space between `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=` and the new library path.

Comment: I edited your question.  I suggest you edit it and look at what syntax I used to produce that result.  And @GordonDavisson is right :)

Comment: Oh thanks to both of you guys, this question was a waste of time!! This post was completly unecessary... the solution is more than trivial. :l